# TCP Connection with Virtual IP

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I've two Servers with different Physical IPs mapped to one Virtual IP in a cluster. So that when one down other can take place of it.

At a time only one Server will be Active and will Listen to the client's request through TCP Server Socket. I am using Java for this.

Now if I try to use `ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)`, with Physical IP, it works fine.
But when I use Virtual IP, it gives me bind exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
```

I've also tried to open ServerSocket using PORT only `(ServerSocket(int port))`. When I connect it from the Client Application using Physical IP, it works but not connects with Virtual IP and ends up with connection reset exception.

I need to connect on a single IP so that Client Application need not to be changed when Passive server becomes Active.

Comment: Did you try to bind to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: No, How will it help?? Do I need to provide host entry? Will I able to connect with virtual IP from the client application??

Comment: I tried binding with 0.0.0.0, server runs without error. But client can't connect with IP 0.0.0.0 throws connection exception. I tried using virtual IP also, result is same. Works only when physical IP is provided in client application

Comment: The client should still connect in the same way as before. The 0.0.0.0 means that your listening socket is bound to all addresses on your server.

Comment: I did a work around, may be this is correct. I made entry of virtual IP in both server's host file and started the server program bound to that IP on Active Server. Now when I manually down the Active Server and Start Server Process bound to the same virtual IP on Passive Server (that is now Active) it works! Only one issue, client program doesn't throw exception when connection breaks and there is no response of new requests on the same connection. I need to reconnect to the server in order to get the response. Please suggest if something can be done for this